# Gradle project refresh failed Unable to get the CMake

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laNcn.png)**"Gradle 'projectname' project refresh failed"**

This is the error message that is being displayed when i start android studio. how to rectify this? My android studio version is 3.0
Thanks in advance

> Error:Unable to get the CMake version located at:
>   C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\bin

Answer (score 20):

You need to install CMake from the SDK tools.

Open File > Settings.
Select Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
Switch to the SDK Tools tab.
Check CMake. Apply.

Answer (score 0):

Open Preference >  Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. Switch to the SDK Tools tab. Check CMake. Apply