# Unable to get the CMake version located at: C:\Users\Ali Musa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\bin

Tags: java, android, cmake

I am trying to install Android Studio and I am getting the the error message:

> Unable to get the CMake version located at: C:\Users\Ali Musa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\bin

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of your project? You seem to have enabled Native C++ support without having the right dependencies.

Comment: Check out this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436937/gradle-project-refresh-failed-unable-to-get-the-cmake